# Prove that $\frac{(1-x_1)(1-x_2) \cdots (1-x_n)}{x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n} \geq (n-1)^n$ for $x_i > 0$ and $x_1 + \ldots + x_n = 1$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, products, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

It is the problem 2.3 in [Algebraic Inequalities](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319778358) by Sedrakyan & Sendrakyan.

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIjIF.png)

I can't figure out how to prove the key inequality in the solution:

$$\frac{(1-x_1)(1-x_2)}{x_1x_2} \geq \frac{(1-\frac{1}{n})(1-x_1 - x_2 + \frac{1}{n})}{\frac{1}{n}(x_1 + x_2 - \frac{1}{n})}$$

The problem 1.17 referenced in the solution had the following inequality:

$$\lambda(x_1 + x_2 - \lambda) \geq x_1x_2  \text{        for    } x_1 \leq \lambda \leq x_2$$

Substituting $\frac{1}{n}$ for $\lambda$ we have $$\frac{1}{n}(x_1 + x_2 - \frac{1}{n}) \geq x_1x_2 \iff \frac{1}{x_1x_2} \geq \frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}(x_1 + x_2 - \frac{1}{n})}$$

The denominators are fine but we still don't have the full inequality and I'm not sure how to get to it. I imagine I must be missing something simple because otherwise the solution would spend more time on this inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{1}{n}(x_1 + x_2 - \frac{1}{n}) \geq x_1x_2 \\
\Rightarrow 1+\frac{1-x_1-x_2}{x_1 x_2} \geq 1+ \frac{1-x_1-x_2}{\frac{1}{n} (x_1+x_2-\frac{1}{n})} \\
\Rightarrow \frac{(1-x_1)(1-x_2)}{x_1 x_2} \geq \frac{(1-\frac 1n) (1-x_1-x_2+\frac 1n)}{\frac 1n (x_1+x_2-\frac 1n)}.
$$

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate a quick solution!

Answer (score 2):

By AM-GM $$1-x_i=\sum_{k\neq i}x_k\geq(n-1)\sqrt[n-1]{\prod_{k\neq i}x_k}.$$
Thus, $$\prod_{i=1}^n(1-x_i)\geq(n-1)^n\prod_{i=1}^n x_i$$ and we are done!

Comment: Thanks, it's much better than the solution in the book!

Comment: @rak You are welcome!